# How can I know that an input MediaDeviceInfo returned on navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices(), is actually an external one

Tags: javascript, webrtc

When I run `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` in chrome and I have no input devices connected, it returns only the output audio deviceInfo. When I do it in Firefox it always returns a few audio input devices that are system audio. How can I know if that input device is an external one?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way to identify external devices with `enumerateDevices()` is to filter out internal ones by `label`. And what is left is external. Device list will contain device in format like this:

```
InputDeviceInfo
deviceId: "9d6e3ef425928764340c9927aca8ed229c0133f52b13e503c6d1726750fbdb02"
groupId: "2e16224d6094a619c3dcc965a83d5c64d7d9020ebe8fda00182bb482bb9cb84b"
kind: "audioinput"
label: "MacBook Pro Microphone (Built-in)"
```

**Built-in** means this is an internal device. For more information look in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices).

Comment: I can find no information that the label is a certain criteria that a device is internal or external. Does every internal device on every computer has the "built-in" in its label?

Comment: This is not reliable and basically only works by chance on certain devices (like the Apple used in the example. As [the spec clearly says](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dom-mediadeviceinfo-deviceid) „This label is intended to allow the end user to tell the difference between devices. **Applications can’t assume that the label contains any specific information**, such as the device type or model.“

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the current spec as of 16 June 2022, there is no built-in [constraint](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dom-mediatrackconstraints) to differentiate between internal and external devices.

Things that you **can** do with constraints that may be worth pointing out:

1. The [`groupId`](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#def-constraint-groupId) allows to determine which audio & video devices sit in the same physical hardware entity, such as the internal mic and cam. However, in my test i found that the audio & video input of my external cam *did* share the same `groupId` as expected, but the internal audio & video did not :(
2. The [`facingMode`](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dfn-facingmode) allows to select a preference for user-facing or environment-facing cam.

However, unless you find or build a well-populated database of device labels that provides this internal / external information, i'm afraid there is currently no reliable means to achieve that differentiation.

One could only hope that this would be included in the W3C draft at some point, however there won't likely be any guarantee that browser & devices vendors will implement that bit thoroughly.